# Misplacement while adding shapefile with no projection

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, qgis-3, canada

I'm stuck trying to add a shapefile of points (digitised from geotagged aerial pictures, I'm assuming GPS tagged) in QGIS 3.4 (Mac). The `.prj`-file that I opened in notepad gives me a WGS84 GCS.

```
GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]
```

But when I add the shapefile in QGIS, and I click on the info button to see the "coordinates" it's in metrics. The layout of points seems correct just their.

The area is in the Mackenzie Delta in the NorthWest Territories, Canada. I tried pseudo mercator (EPSG:3857), conic Lambert (EPSG:3978 and EPSG:3581), UTM 8 (EPSG:26908), the values are just off (it's like they just "slid").

Any idea how to fix this so the points would be at their actual accurate locations?

[image: example]

Comment: Have you checked the projection in the Layer properties dialogue, Source tab? Is it 4326 (WGS84)? What is the projection of the canvas? In the lower right corner you can see the EPSG ID of the projection. The click position is in the canvas projection What are the coordinates in your layer? Check them with 'ogrinfo -a' or set projection of the canvas to the projection of your layer.

Comment: Hi Zoltan, of course I used WGS84 first by default, the projection in the layer properties is WGS84 (4326 indeed), so is the projection in the canvas (4326 as well as I have the on the fly activated). Then the coordinates in my layers are like in the snapshot given above, for example for a point: X: -2999170, Y: 9492714 which are not coordinates for a geographic coordinates system... So I'm assuming the projection set is incorrect and simultaneously I have no idea which projection to choose as whatever logical choice I made, the points are never where they are supposed to be...

Comment: You may try projfinder (http://projfinder.com/)  if you know the location of your map.